# Convert HTML into PDF break by page

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pdf

Recently I'm working on a function which involve html template.

What this function does is to generate a dynamic template, and convert it into an pdf.

So far, i manage to do it like this

```
var output = '';
async.each(input.contentInfo, function(component, next) {
    renderTemplate(component, function(err, result){ //compile input and template together
        output = output + result; //merge all component's html source code together
        next();
    });
}, function(err) {
    conversion({        //phantom-html-to-pdf function from npm module
        html: output,
        paperSize: {
            format: 'A8', 
            orientation: 'landscape',
            margin: 0,
            headerHeight: 0,
            footerHeight: 0
        }
    }, function(err, pdf) {
        var output = fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');
        pdf.stream.pipe(output);
    });
});
```

Assuming everything works fine over here because I did't show any error checking around the example.

Now, the `output` variable would be something like this

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:100;top:100;>
        Page 1 Content
    </div>
</div>
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
    <div style="position:absolute;left:100;top:100;>
        Page 2 Content
    </div>
</div>
```

The result I expected to see when the html convert to PDF, would be 2 pages due to the `page-break` CSS, but in this case, it doesn't. But if using the same output without the `position: absolute` CSS, it work as I expected but the UI is not right.

Is there any solution for this situation to achieve both of the requirement?

Any help to this will be appreciated and sorry if I explain the situation bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [npm module](https://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf) documentation directed me to [this page](https://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf), where the section on "Page Breaks" has this to say:

```
Css contains styles like page-break-before you can use to specify html page 
breaks. This can be used as well with phantom-pdf to specify page breaks 
inside pdf files.

    <h1>Hello from Page 1</h1>

    <div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>

    <h1>Hello from Page 2</h1>

    <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>

    <h1>Hello from Page 3</h1>
```

**Short answer:** try `page-break-before: always;` instead.

Comment: The phantomjs project is archived. They recommend using Chrome pdf recipe.